# Set Custom Price to Quote item magento2 from controller

Tags: magento2, checkout, price, addtocart

I am adding the product to the cart with below code.

```
class AddItems extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

   protected $formKey;   
   protected $cart;
   protected $product;
   protected $checkoutSession;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,     
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;  
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
  public function execute()
  {
        $productId = 1;
        $customPrice = 150;
        $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product_id' => $ProductId, //product Id
            'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product                
        );          

            $_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);      
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
            $this->cart->save();

            $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
            $quoteId = $quote->getId();
            $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product);
            $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
            $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice); 
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
 }

 public function getProductQuote($product){
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();        
    $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);        
    return $cartItems;
   }

}
```

I am adding custom price to the quote item with above code. Its not updating the custom price.

Can anyone look into this and update me please. Thanks

Comment: you can add ? this one `$productItem->save();`

Comment: also check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/248218/68695

Comment: @RakeshDonga, Yes tried save() method, that did not work for me

Comment: you can add last of execute function `$productItem->save();` `$this->cart->save();`

Comment: @RakeshDonga, can you please update the answer, I am not cleared

Comment: @jafarpinjar Did you use Observer or Plugin to do this controller or override the controller please update

Comment: @Sabareesh, This i used it in my own controller,

Comment: @jafarpinjar I also need to set custom price so can you update hoe to do it

Comment: @Sabareesh, try the accepted answer, it worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,
In your controller add the below code to make it work

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\Product;                           
class AddProduct extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action                 
{
protected $formKey;
protected $cart;
protected $product;
protected $checkoutSession;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    array $data = []) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
    $productId = 1;
    $customPrice = 150;
    $params = array(
        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
        'product_id' => $productId, //product Id
        'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product
    );
    $_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    //$quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
    //$quoteId = $quote->getId();
    $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product);
    //$productItem->setPrice($customPrice);
    //$productItem->setBasePrice($customPrice);
    $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
    $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
    //Enable super mode on the product.
    $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $this->cart->save();
    echo "success";
}

public function getProductQuote($product)
{
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $cartItem = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
    return $cartItem;
}}
```

There the problem was you saved the cart before setting the custom price.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: we can not get the $ quoteId until we save the item. I think the above code is not proper

Comment: You doesn't need quoteId and moreover $quoteId is not been used there it seems, I've updated it and try this code and it does working fine.
Thanks

Comment: hi @Prathap,  this code adds 1 qty each time it is called, can we set only one qty in cart by removing previously added item

Comment: Yes we can do that get quote by product id and if exist remove the item from quote and let your run after that @jafarpinjar

Comment: Is it possible to update that code pls? @Prathap

Comment: That's an separate context give it as another question we'll sort it out because this answer will affect other if we made lots of modification in it

Comment: yes, I have requested separate question here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265396/allow-only-one-item-into-cart-in-magento2, can you pls look into it

Comment: So when it called twice in the sense it will 2 in the cart right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90910/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-prathap-gunasekaran).

Comment: hi @Prathap, check your chat

Comment: can we set tax also with this scenario?