# Allow only one qty of item into cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart, controllers

I have created a custom controller in my module and calling via ajax to add the item to cart.

Below is my controller code.

```
<?php 

 namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\Product;                           
 class AddProduct extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action                 
{
 protected $formKey;
 protected $cart;
 protected $product;
 protected $checkoutSession;
 public function __construct(
 \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
 \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
 \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
 \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
 array $data = []) {
  $this->formKey = $formKey;
  $this->cart = $cart;
  $this->product = $product;
  $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
  parent::__construct($context);
  }
  public function execute()
  {
  $productId = 1;
  $customPrice = 150;
  $params = array(
    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
    'product_id' => $productId, //product Id
    'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product
  );
  $_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);
  $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);

  $productItem = $this->getProductQuote($_product);
  $productItem->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
  $productItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
  //Enable super mode on the product.
  $productItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
  $this->cart->save();
  echo "success";
 }


 public function getProductQuote($product)
 {
  $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
  $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
  return $cartItems;
 } 
}
```

The above code adds the product of qty 1 to the cart with a custom price whenever it is called.

I want to add only 1 qty of product to the cart. suppose if its called two or three times, only one qty should be present in cart. Need to remove previously added qty from the cart.

Is something can be done programmatically? There is a product setting in backend "Maximum qty allowed in cart", we can set this value but I am looking for the code how it can be done programmatically.

Can anyone look into it and help me, please. Thanks

Comment: Try the below answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getItemByProduct`

> If Item is exist -> use `addProduct` function -> else -> use `updateItem` function

```
$item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($_product);
if ($item) {
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
} else {
    $this->cart->updateItem($item->getId(), 1);
}
```

Comment: hi, Thank you, but you are doing reversely I think,

Comment: hi, this code doesn't work for me

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works. Item qty always = 1

Comment: what about custom price? for me it didn't work,

Comment: You need call collectTotals function for calculate price

Comment: hi @bang. can u update to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Why you do that programmatically ? You can set it by Magento 2 configuration :

> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options -> Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart

Set **1** here. It will working.

**EDIT :**

**events.xml :**

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
  <observer name="vendor_model_cart_add_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CartAddBefore" />
</event>
```

**CartAddBefore.php :**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class CartAddBefore implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_cart;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_request;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    ) {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_request = $request;        
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $postValues = $this->_request->getPostValue();
        $cartItemsCount = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount();

        if($cartItemsCount > 1)
        {
            ...... your logic .......
            $this->_messageManager->addError(__('Sorry, Only 1 product is allowed'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this option is there, but we are not using admin feature as per the requirement, trying to handle programmatically, that's why i mentioned in question

Comment: so, trying to delete old quote from id and update with new one. If enabled the above setting the error message will be shown to the user, we are avoiding that one

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: I am calling the controller from ajax request, so can you please help me in giving answer for removing old quote of the product, and add new one, because i don't want to show any error message to the customer, @Rohan, The requirement is like that pls